# Have number value in SQL - I want to subtract it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want a changeable attribute (CARS) in table SQL -> after click on `sendForm`, amount should subtract 1 and echo this changes.

In this part I'm stuck: I made a table in SQL with amount of cars (30). How can I make it subtract after Event-> click on form?

Is there a way to subtract automatic?

```
$sql = "UPDATE wp_cars_forms SET cars_num = 55 WHERE form_id = 1";
```

Comment: do you prefer AJAX or  only FORM method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current value of the column in your update query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE wp_cars_forms SET cars_num = cars_num -1 WHERE form_id = 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note, when you are doing this, you often want to prevent the value from going negative:

```
UPDATE wp_cars_forms
    SET cars_num = cars_num - 1
    WHERE form_id = 1 AND cars_num > 0;
```

This makes the query truly atomic.